# I've got this error in django : Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "users-detail"

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

everybody.

I created an app named as credentials.

these are my code files:

credentials `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
class Users(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    inserted_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('username',)

class UsersDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        Users,
        related_name='id_user_details',
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
    )
    user_title = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    user_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    user_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    user_birthdate = models.DateField(blank=False)
    inserted_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    details_creator = models.ForeignKey(
        Users,
        related_name='dtlcreator_user_details',
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        # default=1
        )
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('user_id',)

class UsersPasswords(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        Users,
        related_name='id_user_password',
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    salt = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    pwdhash = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    inserted_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    pwd_creator = models.ForeignKey(
        Users,
        related_name='pwdcreator_user_details',
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('user_id',)
```

credentials `serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from credentials.models import Users
from credentials.models import UsersDetails
from credentials.models import UsersPasswords

class UsersSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
details = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    many=True,
    read_only=True,
    view_name='user-details'
)
passwords = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    many=True,
    read_only=True,
    view_name='user-passwords'
)

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = (
            'url',
            'pk',
            'username',
            'inserted_timestamp',
            'details',
            'passwords',
        )

class UsersDetailsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='user-list')
    creator = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='user-list')

    class Meta:
        model = UsersDetails
        fields = (
            'url',
            'pk',
            'user',
            'user_title',
            'user_first_name',
            'user_last_name',
            'user_birthdate',
            'inserted_timestamp',
            'creator'
        )

class UsersPasswordsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='user-list')
    creator = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='user-list')

    class Meta:
        model = UsersPasswords
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'user',
            'salt',
            'pwdhash',
            'inserted_timestamp',
            'creator'
            )
```

Credentails `views.py`:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from credentials.models import Users, UsersDetails, UsersPasswords
from credentials.serializers import UsersSerializer, UsersDetailsSerializer, UsersPasswordsSerializer

class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Users.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UsersSerializer
    name = 'user-list'

class UserDetails(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = UsersDetails.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UsersDetailsSerializer
    name = 'user-details'

class UserPasswords(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = UsersPasswords.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UsersPasswordsSerializer
    name = 'user-passwords'

class ApiRoot(generics.GenericAPIView):
    name = 'api-root'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({
            'user-list': reverse(UserList.name, request=request),
            'user-details': reverse(UserDetails.name, request=request),
            'user-passwords': reverse(UserPasswords.name, request=request),
        })
```

Credentials `URLs`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from credentials import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^user-list/$',
        views.UserList.as_view(),
        name=views.UserList.name),
    url(r'^user-list/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$',
        views.UserList.as_view(),
        name=views.UserList.name),
    url(r'^user-details/$',
        views.UserDetails.as_view(),
        name=views.UserDetails.name),
    url(r'^user-details/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$',
        views.UserDetails.as_view(),
        name=views.UserDetails.name),
    url(r'^user-passwords/$',
        views.UserPasswords.as_view(),
        name=views.UserPasswords.name),
    url(r'^user-passwords/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$',
        views.UserPasswords.as_view(),
        name=views.UserPasswords.name),
    url(r'^$',
        views.ApiRoot.as_view(),
        name=views.ApiRoot.name),
]
```

Database parameters in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '****',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'HOST': '************',
        'PORT': '****',
    }
}
```

I've done migration and everything looks good.

When I request `http://localhost:2281/auth/user-list/` it raises below error:
`Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "users-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the`lookup_field`attribute on this field.`

I found nothing like "users-detail" in my code and I don't know why it raises this error.

Of course you should know that this error raises just after saving new user and when I see the database I find stored record of new user. but I don't know why this happened.

Thanks a lot for your attentions.

Comment: I think you are using `views.UserDetails.name` at 2 places.  Give a try by replacing `name=views.UserPasswords.name`  with `name="test_name"` and then check.

Comment: similarly for user-password

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool I didn't read enough about django rest framework. My question totally was wrong. Sorry about wasting your time and thank you for your efforts. I wish I could remove it. It needs too much modifications to work properly. I currently  solved the problem.